# Is there a benefit from using a dock to charge wireless controllers

Tags: ps4, controllers, hardware

I now have a PS4 with a wireless controller. Is there a compelling reason to use a charging station, other than aesthetics?

Comment: Convenience. You don't have to mess around with the cable, you just plop the controller onto the dock and you're good to go.

Comment: Are the aesthetics of a charging station not compelling?

Comment: @JAB "It looks nice/pretty" is not a compelling reason to buy something that is not necessary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some charging docks uses the EXT port rather than the micro USB. This saves wear and tear on the USB port and, according to several reviews, is faster.

You also have the advantage of not needing a USB cable, as well as saving energy by not needing to leave the PS4 on.

Comment: Some dock stations still use micro USB port - for example, this one https://www.amazon.com/UGREEN-Compatible-Controller-Controllers-PlayStation/dp/B071KX7WPH/ref=sr_1_13?ie=UTF8&qid=1546278983&sr=8-13&keywords=ps4+dock+station

Comment: I would think that the charge speed heavily depends on which dock you use, so I would be hesitant to declare that as a benefit. Could easily be a con (I had a junk one that I swore either changes one at a time - it held 2, or took hours to fully charge both). Needless to say I bought a new (different) one within the week..

Comment: Good point, @BrootsWaymb - definitely something to look in to